# Custom Pipe more arguments

Tags: angular

I am trying to do custom pipe which will filter data from table.

I did it like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(employees: any, term: any): any {
    // check if search term is undefined
    if (term === undefined) return employees;
    // return updated array
    return employees.filter(function(alias){
      return alias.name.includes(term);
    });
  }

}
```

It works only for one argument how can I filter any table column with one input (now it filtering only name column)?

There is my html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-4">
        <!-- filter -->
        <form id="filter">
            <label>Search:</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="term" name="filter">
        </form>
        <!-- end -->
        <br>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Dept</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let alias of employees | filter:term">
                    <td>{{ alias.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ alias.dept }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `return alias.name.includes(term) || alias.dept.includes(term);`? But please read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search through all the properties in `alias` using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
return employees.filter(function(alias) {
  let found = false;
  Object.keys(alias).forEach(function(key) { 
      found = found || alias[key].includes(term);
  });
  return found;
});
```

Or this can be expressed more tersely with arrow functions `=>` and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control):

```
return employees.filter(alias => 
    Object.keys(alias).reduce(
        (found, key) => found || alias[key].includes(term), false
    )
);
```

Or even better with `Object.values()` (but [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility) currently isn't as good so you'll need to [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js) it):

```
return employees.filter(alias =>
    Object.values(alias).reduce(
        (found, value) => found || value.includes(term), false
    )
);
```

But @JBNizet's comment is spot on - you probably don't want to do this in a pipe. Much better to move that logic into the the component class.